# Make it 1 capturing group

Tags: python, regex

From here 
https://regex101.com/r/Cy4Bua/2[image]
you can see that to match the version I have 3 capturing group. Could I make it to only 1 which is the "group 1"?

Comment: What is the expected output you need to get in Python and what are the requirements? For now, it seems you may just use `\d[\d.]*` or `\d+(?:\.\d+)*`

Comment: expected output is Group1 only (full version number matched)
e.g., "hello this is version 1.2.33.4" matched “1.2.33.4”

Comment: You hardly ever need to wrap the whole pattern with a capturing group - are you using it in `re.split`? Please explain what you are doing if my suggestions above do not work for you ([demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/iQCoPs/1), [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/xKDuFz/1)). Please also show the relevant Python code.

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want this:

```
re.match('((\d+.)*(\d))', '1.2.3434.5').group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your simple case it's enough to apply `re.search()` function:

```
import re

s = 'hello this is version 1.2.33.4'
v = re.search(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)*', s).group()

print(v)
```

The output:

```
1.2.33.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one regex:
([\d+.]*\d)